# Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, unix, compare

I've a situation, where I've a source file and a target file, supposed to be similar.
The source file has sets of information like below. I need to compare each set of information in Source and Target files. If anything's missing in Target file, I need to write the line into the target file.
I could have matched line by line, but the sets of Source and target files are not in order.
Please help me how to achieve using a shell script.

Source file:

```
[Set.1]
value=1
date=today

[Set.2]
value=2
date=today
```

Target File:

```
[Set.2]
value=2

[Set.1]
value=1
date=today
```

If you can see, date is missing in [Set.2] of target file, so, I need to copy it from Source File.

Comment: will the data in both files be same or only pattern will be same

Comment: Data will be same. We need to fill the gaps finally to make them identical.

Comment: mv or cp file to target file

Answer (score 0):

by the command below the file_set2 and file_set1 will be compared if any thing missing from file_set2 is present in file_set1 will be copied back to file_set2.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file_set2 file_set1 >>file_set2
```

Comment: This won't work because the line `date=today` is present in both files but not is both locations where it is needed in file_set2.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using rsync

```
rsync /target/file/path /source/file/path
```

Comment: Hello, rsync looks to be an easy option, but my src-file is kind of delta file. tgt_file has more information with missing fields, which can be found in the src-delta files. I just need to copy the contents from src_file, while keeping intact, the target_file.

Answer (score 0):

This is either a very easy problem or a hard one. If you just need to make the files identical then

```
cp source_file target_file
```

would be enough. But it seems like you want to keep the ordering of sections in `target_file` unchanged. This will require you to parse the files first **and** remember the order of the sections.

Since this is Windows INI file format, the ordering of sections should not be significant to the program reading it. Check to make sure whether the reader actually cares.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Like, I mentioned below, src-file is kind of delta, so, by referring multiple src-files, I update my tgt-file. Though ordering is not a problem, the data inside a set can be repeated. So, while grepping in the tgt file, I am required to keep in mind the header line as well...!!